# How to bind values of TextBox and Slider to one another? VB.net (Windows Store)

Tags: vb.net, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want the text in the TextBox to change while I slide the slider, and vice versa (the value of the slider changes as I type in the TextBox). 
Here is the XAML code for the Slider:

```
<Slider x:Name="PercentageSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" Margin="333,319,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="788" Foreground="#FF5D9FAD" Minimum="1" Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=PercentageValueTextBox}"/>
```

And here is for the TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PercentageValueTextBox" Height="46" Margin="0,319,161,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="69" FontSize="26" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=PercentageSlider}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Xaml` is correct for linking your two controls, what is causing the problem is the `Minimum = 1`, that is overriding the ability of the `TextBox` to effect the `Slider`.

Try changing your Binding expressions to:

**TextBox :**

```
   Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=PercentageSlider, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

**Slider  :**

```
Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=PercentageValueTextBox, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: You really just need to add `Mode=TwoWay` to your binding expressions. By default they are set to `Mode=OneWay` in WinRT.

Comment: You did include the correct binding expressions, I just pointed out why `Mode` needs to be changed for someone used to WPF. Also `Minimum` value shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: It doesn't with the TwoWay binding, but it does effect the default binding. His code worked correctly when I removed the minimum, but the TextBox would not update the slider with the Minimum set. That is kind of why the answer is a little bit disjointed

Comment: This works, but the default value is set to 1. Can I set it to 100, so that when I run the program, the slider and the textbox are on 100?

Comment: OK, I just added Slider.Value=100 when the page loads, thanks again guys.

Comment: But, it's kinda not right when I set the value to e.g. 45, and then navigate to other page and back, and the value is back to 100. There's gotta be some other way to do this.

Comment: What are you doing with the value, are you using it in any other part of your program? You will need to persist it in some way either pull the value from another object, create a custom class to store it.

Comment: I'll use that value later in resizing the picture by percentage.

Comment: @A6Tech what you can do is create a class with a shared property and use that for your storage. You can test if its value is nothing then assign your 100%, else restore stored value.

Answer (score 0):

for the textbox:

```
textchanged event:
slider1.value=CInt(textbox1.text)
```

for the slider:

```
valuechanged event:
textbox1.text=slider1.value.tostring()
```

here the textbox is textbox1, and the slider is slider1

Comment: But where do I write that, i thought that should be written in XAML.

Comment: didn't you say it was vb.net in the title? If you are using XAML, the sorry, i don't know xaml

Comment: Well, it is VB.net, with XAML designer.